# Automatically Printscreen from result of formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a procedure in VBA to call a PrintScreen:

```
Sub PrintScreen()
keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0
End Sub
```

I want to call it every ten seconds, when the result of this cell

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(TEXT(F4,"ss")),-ABS(VALUE(RIGHT(F4,2))))
```

is `"0"`;
the next cell returns a `"Yes"` or `"No"` if `"0"`

```
=IF(RIGHT(I5,1)="0","Yes","No")
```

So, when this cell returns `"Yes"` I want to take a screenshot. I know I'm close but it's frustrating me as I can't get it.

Comment: You need to use worksheet_change event to check your `if`s and call the printscreen